# Ruby watir webdriver - how to click on a div link that is dynamically created

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I have a link in my web app that looks like this when inspected in developer tools -

```
<div class="runnable-item alt" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}"><!-- ngIf: item.working -->Rep</div>
```

I need to be able to click on it from within Ruby code using watir webdriver.
I could click on buttons and edit fields so far successfully with code similar to:

```
browser.text_field(id: 'user').set 'test1'
browser.button(id: 'submitBtn').click
browser.a(id: 'start-process').click
```

Now how do I auto-click on a div element as shown above?

Here is a more full HTML code -

```
<div class="row">
<!-- ngRepeat: list in lists --><div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="">
<div class="col-sm-6"><h4>Services</h4>
<!-- ngIf: list.items === undefined -->
<!-- ngIf: list.message --><!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id" class=""><div class="runnable-item" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}">
<!-- ngIf: item.working -->Excel Examples Main (Start here)</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id" class=""><div class="runnable-item alt" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}">
<!-- ngIf: item.working -->Excel Examples</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id" class=""><div class="runnable-item" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}"><!-- ngIf: item.working -->Hello World</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id --></div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: list in lists --><div ng-repeat="list in lists" class="">
<div class="col-sm-6"><h4>Processes</h4><!-- ngIf: list.items === undefined --><!-- ngIf: list.message -->
<!-- ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id" class=""><div class="runnable-item" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}">
<!-- ngIf: item.working -->CompletedExample</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id" class=""><div class="runnable-item alt" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}">
<!-- ngIf: item.working -->SimpleActiveExample</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id -->
<div ng-repeat="item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id" class=""><div class="runnable-item" ng-click="list.click(item)" ng-class="{'alt': $odd, 'disabled': item.working}">
<!-- ngIf: item.working -->Standard HR</div></div>
<!-- end ngRepeat: item in list.items | orderBy:'name' track by item.id --></div></div><!-- end ngRepeat: list in lists --></div>
...
...
```

Comment: It's really difficult to answer your question because the important part is figuring out what is unique about the element relative to all the other elements. Are there other elements with class 'runnable-item' or 'list.click(item)'? It's a bit tricky because Angular uses non-valid html5 tags, and it is much easier for Watir to deal with it when the app developers prepend 'data-' (e.g. data-ng-click vs ng-click)

Comment: Sorry, I did not develop the app itself, so, sorry for the lack of details. Yes, there are many items with the same class name and so, I cannot figure out how to call them within Watir because I can't find smth unique in each of them. So, what kind of extra data I can provide to better illustrate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple items have the same class there are a few options.

1. You can grab all of them using `@browser.divs(class: "runnable-item alt ")`  then iterate over the result using `.each do |element|` checking it for some x property.
2. Make your selection more specific `@browser.div(css: "parent runnable-item:nth-child(2)", text: /text from div/)`

Overall your question needs more context. Give us some more of the html tree so we understand how to solve the problem. Do you want a specific button, a random button, etc.

**Update**: 
You still need to be more specific. Do you want "Processs" OR "Services" or just any random div with the class "runnable-item alt" clicked. If it really is any random button the following should be good enough: 
`@browser.divs(class: "runnable-item alt").sample.click`

If you want to randomly select an item from **either**  the Process section or Services section I would do something like the following:

```
case Random.new.rand(2) 
when 0
  div_section = @browser.h4(text: /Processes/).parent
  div_section.div(class: "runnable-item alt").click
when 1
  div_section = @browser.h4(text: /Services/).parent
  div_section.div(class: "runnable-item alt").click
end
```

In either case you need to be more deterministic about what you want to do with the test. Create variance with multiple test cases that have a defined workflow rather then one test case that randomly clicks different buttons.

Comment: Thank you! I have added a more complete HTML code to the original post. Either random link or specific link (let's say first in that list) would work for my test. So, basically in a list of Proceses and services you can see above (in DIVs) I need to pick any of those using Watir and launch it, e..g click on it.

Comment: thank you! see my response also on how I did it. Yes, I basically want to call any random item and I know the name of items in advance. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the solution was simpler than I anticipated.
Using Watir you can select div elements based on text value, so, it works great for my use case.

The code to click/call "CompletedExample" from above HTML would look like -

```
b.div(:text, 'CompletedExample').click
```